# "cannot import name IncompleteRead" error when running pip

Tags: linux, python, pip

When I install python-pip it shows it is install allready installed, but when I am using `pip` command, below error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

[image]

Comment: Please make sure to preview your posts and use the correct formatting. Use the body to decscribe your problem, not just the title. Which Linux distribution is that?

Comment: BOSS operating system @slhck

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this OS ships with an outdated version of `pip`. In general, that means you should probably find a distribution that has more frequent updates, if you still encounter this issue.

What you can do is try to get a newer version without `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
```

Other solutions are posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341064/how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread).